# Getting Fatal Exception with Tabs in Android application

Tags: android, tabs, fatal-error

I am getting Fatal Exception while running the application and in Emulator it gives "Force Close".

Here is the LogCat content,

```
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demotab/com.demotab.DemotabActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:649)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at com.demotab.DemotabActivity.onCreate(DemotabActivity.java:36)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-28 22:01:14.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11421):     ... 11 more
```

Please guide me how can I resolve it.

Comment: Check this thread. See if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272500/android-exception-did-you-forget-to-call-public-void-setup-localactivitymanage

Comment: I have done,
tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());
with extending ActivityGroup,
I have intent to include another activity, now while changing tabs, tab content is getting overlapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution,
extended my class with ActivityGroup instead of Activity and added

tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());