# Can i have multiple tabhost?

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I'm working on an update for my app, and i just added another tabhost but i keep getting errors. The first tabhost activity extends TabActivity. I tried to do that with the second one, but it didn't work so i went back to extends activity. Then i started to get other errors. I was looking at the logcat and one of the errors was referring to my first tabhost activity, so i'm kind of confused about that. I dont know what to do though.

Heres the logcat

```
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to      start activity      ComponentInfo{com.TBJsoft.enclosurecalculator/tbjsoft.enclosurecalculator.DiagramTabHost}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at tbjsoft.enclosurecalculator.DiagramTabHost.onCreate(DiagramTabHost.java:37)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-04 15:50:52.814: E/AndroidRuntime(23237):    ... 11 more
```

Here's the first tabhost

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host);
    build();
}

public void build(){
    vas = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("vas",0);
    fs = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("fs",0);
    qts = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("qts",0);
    qes = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("qes",0);
    slotWidth = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("slotWidth",0);
    slotHeight = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("slotHeight",0);
    portDiameter = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("portDiameter",0);
    sVolume = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("sealedVolume",0);
    pVolume = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("portedVolume",0);
    fb = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("fb", 0);

    tabHost = getTabHost();

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Specs");
    spec.setIndicator("Specs");
    Intent calculate = new Intent(this, Calculate.class);
    calculate.putExtra("vas", vas);
    calculate.putExtra("fs", fs);
    calculate.putExtra("qts", qts);
    calculate.putExtra("qes", qes);
    calculate.putExtra("slotWidth", slotWidth);
    calculate.putExtra("slotHeight", slotHeight);
    calculate.putExtra("portDiameter", portDiameter);
    spec.setContent(calculate);

    dimensions = tabHost.newTabSpec("Dimensions");
    dimensions.setIndicator("Dimensions");
    Intent dimension = new Intent(this,BoxDimensions.class);
    dimension.putExtra("sVolume",sVolume);
    dimension.putExtra("pVolume",pVolume);
    dimensions.setContent(dimension);

    ports = tabHost.newTabSpec("Ports");
    ports.setIndicator("Ports");
    Intent port = new Intent(this, Ports.class);
    port.putExtra("fb", fb);
    port.putExtra("pVolume", pVolume);
    ports.setContent(port);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.addTab(dimensions);
    tabHost.addTab(ports);

}
```

}

Here's the second one

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagram_tab_host);
    tabHost = (android.widget.TabHost) findViewById(R.id.wdTabHost);
    in = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("imageName");

    if(in.get(4).equals("1")){

        String imageName = in.get(0) + in.get(1) + in.get(2) + in.get(3) + in.get(4);

        diagram = tabHost.newTabSpec("Diagram");
        diagram.setIndicator("Diagram");
        Intent d = new Intent(DiagramTabHost.this, Diagram.class);
        d.putExtra("imageName",imageName);
        diagram.setContent(d);

        tabHost.addTab(diagram);

    }else{

        String imageName = in.get(0) + in.get(1) + in.get(2) + in.get(3) + in.get(4);

        parallel = tabHost.newTabSpec("Parallel");
        parallel.setIndicator("Parallel");
        Intent p = new Intent(DiagramTabHost.this, Parallel.class);
        p.putExtra("imageName",imageName);
        parallel.setContent(p);

        series = tabHost.newTabSpec("Series");
        series.setIndicator("Series");
        Intent s = new Intent(DiagramTabHost.this, Series.class);
        s.putExtra("imageName",imageName);
        series.setContent(s);

        tabHost.addTab(parallel);
        tabHost.addTab(series);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you need to call `setup()` before adding tabs if loading TabHost using `findViewById()`.

```
tabHost = (android.widget.TabHost) findViewById(R.id.wdTabHost);
tabHost.setup();
```

I'm basically quoting directly from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setup%28%29).

Comment: I just tried that and it gave me another error, 06-04 18:14:35.746: E/AndroidRuntime(29923): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.TBJsoft.enclosurecalculator/tbjsoft.enclosurecalculator.DiagramTabHost}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862607/getting-fatal-exception-with-tabs-in-android-application

Comment: So you're calling `tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());` and it's still giving you an error saying `Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'`? Or are you getting a different error now?

Comment: Hey, i got it now. That actually did work, I'm just getting an error in the activities the tabhost tries to load. I'm going to try to fix these now, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this in my app ["Droid Bones"] without success. You can see my workaround structure if you install "Droid Bones" in an android device.

Comment: My reading is that TabActivity is an extended Activity and an Activity cannot contain another Activity. And, an ActivityGroup is just that: a collection of [peer] activities.