# Android Tab Menu not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a MenuTab with android but I have a lot of problems. Here's my code

```
tabHost = (TabHost) A.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabHost.setup();
TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_news");
spec1.setIndicator(
    "", //Load news titlte
    A.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_menu_news) //Load icon
);

spec1.setContent(R.id.tab_news);
tabHost.addTab(spec1);
```

First question, why if I put "title" inside indicator I don't see the image?

Well now I want to create a new activity when this tab is selected.

```
TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
firstTabSpec.setIndicator("First Tab Name").setContent(new Intent(A,Test.class));
```

This example doesn't work... I get this error

09-15 23:19:26.861: E/AndroidRuntime(14938): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.workactivity/com.workactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?

I try to google about setup but I get no matchs...

I follow this tutorial: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1
And this one: http://android-pro.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/tabbed-applications-in-android.html

Thanks for all :)

Comment: have you registred your Test activity in the Android Manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, sounds like just the same problem [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272500/android-exception-did-you-forget-to-call-public-void-setup-localactivitymanag). 
While not seeing your code maybe you need change `Activity` base class from `Activity` to `ActivityGroup`