# unable to start activity null pointer exception(on starting new intent)

Tags: android, eclipse

Unable to start activity.

I have a previous page which works fine normally, however when i make a call to the Order_disp page, the error pops up and app stops working.
the code is as follows

```
Order_disp.java

package com.example.sopa;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class Order_disp extends Activity {
    ListView orderdisp;
    ArrayList<OrderListdata> myList_Ord=new ArrayList<OrderListdata>();
    Context context;
    SQLiteHelper sqh=new SQLiteHelper(context);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_disp);
        orderdisp=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ordView1);
        getInList();
                orderdisp.setAdapter(new Badap_Ord(Order_disp.this,myList_Ord));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.order_disp, menu);
        return true;
    }
    void getInList(){
        myList_Ord=sqh.getOrder();

    }

}


SQLiteHelper.java

package com.example.sopa;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_Name = "OrderTab";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
      public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";
      Context context;
      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
      ArrayList<OrderListdata> myList_order=new ArrayList<OrderListdata>();
      // Database creation sql statement
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table IF NOT EXISTS "
          + TABLE_Name + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement,DishName text not null,Quant text not null,Price text not null );";

      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "create table BillTab (Id integer primary key autoincrement,DishName text not null,Quant text not null,Price text not null);";


      public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1);
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(SQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Name);
        onCreate(db);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BillTab");
        onCreate(db);
      }


      void addOrder(ContentValues values) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            // Inserting Row
            db.insert("OrderTab", null, values);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "You hav entered data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }
      ArrayList<OrderListdata> getOrder()
      {

          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          String cols[] = new String[] {"id","DishName","Quant","Price"};

            Cursor cur = db.query("OrderTab",cols,null,null,null,null, null);

            String result = "";

            while(cur.moveToNext()){

                OrderListdata ld=new OrderListdata();
                ld.setDname(cur.getString(1));
                ld.setPrice(cur.getString(2));
                ld.setQtyval(cur.getString(3));
                myList_order.add(ld);

            }
return myList_order;
      }


}
OrderListdata.java

package com.example.sopa;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

public class OrderListdata {
    String dname;
    View cv;
    String qtyval;
    String price;
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {

        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getDname() {
        return dname;
    }
    public void setDname(String dname) {

        this.dname = dname;
    }
    public String getQtyval() {
        return qtyval;
    }
    public void setQtyval(String qtyval) {
        final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) cv.findViewById(R.id.setqty);
        np.setValue(Integer.parseInt(qtyval));
        this.qtyval = qtyval;
    }


}
activity_order_disp.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Order_disp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ordView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

orderdisp.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UnknownIdInLayout" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Dishname"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="123dp"
        android:text="Remove Dish" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/setqty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="94dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/remove" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Dishname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:text="Dishname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>

Manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sopa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sopa.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sopa.Main_menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
            >
        </activity>
         <activity
        android:name="com.example.sopa.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.sopa.Main_menu" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.sopa.Main_menu" />
    </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sopa.Indian"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_indian" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sopa.Chinese"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chinese" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sopa.Italian"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_italian" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sopa.Mexican"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mexican" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.sopa.Order_disp"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
 03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sopa/com.example.sopa.Order_disp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.example.sopa.SQLiteHelper.getOrder(SQLiteHelper.java:62)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.example.sopa.Order_disp.getInList(Order_disp.java:29)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.example.sopa.Order_disp.onCreate(Order_disp.java:18)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-03 01:05:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks in anticipation..

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[Android Exception: Did you forget to call 'public void setup (LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272500/android-exception-did-you-forget-to-call-public-void-setup-localactivitymanag)

Change this

```
 setContentView(R.id.th2);
```

to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); // needs a layout
```

Where is the layout for Second Activity. There is not layout set to Second Activity

Edit:

Change

```
 SQLiteHelper sqh=new SQLiteHelper(context);
```

to

```
SQLiteHelper sqh;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_disp);
    sqh=new SQLiteHelper(this);
```

Comment: answer not relevant to given question

Comment: @user3156575 what? What is so irrelevant in my post. You have edited you post 3 minutes ago. At the time of posting this answer was relevant

Comment: sorry i ment irrelevant to present question
on has been changed. Your answer was correct for previous question. I am not able to post new question hence altered old one. Kindly help me out

Comment: yes it was and thanks for that help.
kindly help me out again

Comment: @user3156575 you should never change the question as it is not helpful to people who visit the post. Secondly a new problem should be posted in a new post. Revert back to old post. Thirdly you have NUllPointerException

Comment: i was not allowed to post new question hence changed, i know i shouldnt hav done sorry but had no other choice. And i saw the null pointer exception but couldnt find where it was.

Comment: @user3156575 Well no choice or not allowed its wrong. KIdnly revert back the changes and check the edit. You can always put a edit section under your question and post the updates. If you continue making mistakes on SO it will lead to more punishment on SO leading to bans. Please visit help center. http://stackoverflow.com/help and visit http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: ill make it a point not to do that from hence forth.
and no that doesnt help either same error

Comment: the suggestion above isnt solving the problem .

Comment: @user3156575 then look @ http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#SQLiteOpenHelper and solve yourself. good luck