# Can I use FragmentManager to replace fragments with activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can I use `FragmentManager` to replace fragments with activity?

Below is my code. I use fragment manager to replace a fragment.
But now I have a class which extends `FragmentActivity` and then I want to use fragmentmanager to replace fragment with it.

```
Fragment fragment2 = new HostFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, activity).commit();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: why? u can make that activity a fragment.

Comment: I'm using fragment manager to replace a fragment with another fragmnet . But as you know , fragment is not an activity and there is something we can not work with fragment so that i change fragment with fragment activity instead. And then the next problem is I can not using fragment manager to replace fragment with fragment activity anymore . And then I'm stuck .

Comment: U can do anything in ur fragment if u have context of activity holding it.

Comment: @keshav here is exactly my problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013031/put-a-tabhost-inside-a-fragment  .This problem will be solved if i use fragment activity instead of fragment . But when i use fragment the new problem is i can not replace this by fragment activity anymore :(

Comment: @keshav I updated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013031/put-a-tabhost-inside-a-fragment

Comment: @keshav my problem will be solved easily if i use fragment activity instead of fragment , but when i change , my above problem is raised :(

Comment: please give me some suggestion . Nearly crazy for searching

Comment: as i seen ur layout, I think u can use viewpager see following links that have viewpager librery  https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator  http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: @keshav I viewed it source code and sadly , it it use fragment activity public class SampleTabsWithIcons extends FragmentActivity  so it has no change with my problem

Comment: why not just convert your fragment activity into a fragment? O.o

Comment: @DanielBo That is what i ask . How can i do it ?

Comment: well, change the class it is extending, and fix the compiler errors. Nothing more i can do without code

Comment: @DanielBo Arcording to what I said in comment above , There is something we can not work with Frament and it must be Fragment Activity in my opinion :( , I try to put an tabshost inside the fragment but I cannot . here is my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013031/put-a-tabhost-inside-a-fragment . So I try another way and change it to fragment activity , It's solved , but when change to fragmentactivity problem is I can not replace a fragment with the fragment activity i have been created. That it . I'm stuck.

Comment: cant try myself without code, but it is possible to add a tabhost to a fragment, did that somewhere, cant remember where xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can only replace fragments with other fragments as `FragmentManager` is handling only fragments. 
If you have in the activity (`ActivityA`) that you want to add some content that you would like to have in current activity (`ActivityB`), then move that content in a separate fragment (`ContentFragment`), load that fragment in `ActivityA` and in `ActivityB`. That's the reason why fragments were introduced.

Comment: I'm using fragment manager to replace a fragment with another fragmnet .And then when i put some component into fragmemt like Tabhost I can not work with it because fragment is not an activity and there is something we can not work with fragment so that i change fragment with fragment activity instead. And then the next problem is I can not using fragment manager to replace fragment with fragment activity anymore . And then I'm stuck .

Comment: here is exactly my problem . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013031/put-a-tabhost-inside-a-fragment This problem will be solved if i use fragment activity instead of fragment . But when i use fragment the new problem is i can not replace this by fragment activity anymore :(

Comment: `TabHost` is a `ViewGroup` why can't you use it?

Comment: I don't get your idea ?

Comment: Yeah ! I voteup beacause your answer is the best for my above question  . But my problem is still there . Anyway , thanks for your reply .