# Tabhost extend Fragment - java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I want add tabhost. Tab 1 is History tab (HistoryActivity.java). Tab 2 is Favorite tab, Tab 3 is Word tab. However when I run, error happens. I don't know reasons. My Class must be extend from Fragment.

Here is TabViewActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

public class TabViewActivity extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TabHost tabHost;
    private View mRoot;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_view, null);
        tabHost = (TabHost) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        // Get TabHost Refference
        tabHost.setup();

        // Set TabChangeListener called when tab changed
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        /************* TAB1 ************/
        // Create Intents to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HistoryActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("").setContent(intent);
        // Add intent to tab
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        /************* TAB2 ************/
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FavouriteActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        /************* TAB3 ************/
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WoDActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Set drawable images to tab
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favourite_off);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wod_off);

    //   Set Tab1 as Default tab and change image
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.history_on);
        return mRoot;

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        /************ Called when tab changed *************/

        // ********* Check current selected tab and change according images
        // *******/

        for (int i = 0; i <tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.history_off);
            else if (i == 1)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favourite_off);
            else if (i == 2)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wod_off);
        }

        Log.i("tabs", "CurrentTab: " + tabHost.getCurrentTab());

        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.history_on);
        else if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favourite_on);
        else if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 2)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wod_on);

    }

}
```

activity_tab_view.xml

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

HistoryActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class HistoryActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.tab_history);
        }
}
```

tab_history.xml

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!--  Screen Design for Food tab -->
   <TextView android:text="FOOD TAB DATA"
             android:padding="15dip"
             android:textSize="18dip"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Error:

```
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:703)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:369)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:247)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.TabViewActivity.onCreateView(TabViewActivity.java:42)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-22 22:21:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26289):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: _Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?_

Comment: what can I do? I tried but error also happens

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272500/ check this, it might help you.

Comment: Thanks you but my class must extends from Fragments. if extends from Activity, it runs ok :(

Comment: What exactly you don't understand from the exception you get? You're using as the content for the tabs an `Intent` which for the `TabHost` means you're using child activities as tabs(in which case you need to call that specific method). You can't embed activities in fragments and you shouldn't use child activities anyway as that is deprecated. You probably want some nested fragments, look at `FragmentTabHost`.

Comment: The easy way is to use a `FragmentTabHost`, you have an example right in the documentation page. Otherwise, use the simple `TabHost`(without setting the content(use the TabContentFactory to return a 0 width/heigh` `View`)) but you'll have to manage the fragments yourself, there are tutorials for this also.

Comment: I created a project based on :http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. When I selected an item on left slide menu, a screen is displayed include: 

`--------------
Action bar
--------------
Tab 1 | Tab2 | Tab3


--------------

--------------`
Because I created tabhost in an other project (TabViewActivity extends from Activity), so when I insert it in project NavigationDrawer I meet problem