# Tabhost to launch new page via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I am trying to open new page on tab selection...
when i launch project it suddenly crashes...

Here is the source... 
(Log Error is your content must have a tabshost whose id attribute is R.id.tabhost)

```
 public class AddFriends_Activity extends TabActivity implements SwipeInterface {
TabHost mTabHost;
 Resources res = getResources();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Added_Friends.class);
        Intent j = new Intent(this,Friend_List.class);
        TabHost mTabHst = getTabHost();
 mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Add Frinds",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.add1))
                .setContent(i));

     mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Friend List",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.add1))
                .setContent(j));


         int tabCount = mTabHst.getTabWidget().getTabCount();
         for (int r = 0; r < tabCount; r++) {
             final View view = mTabHst.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(r);
             if ( view != null ) {
                 // reduce height of the tab
                 view.getLayoutParams().height *= 0.90;

                 //  get title text view
                 final View textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                 if ( textView instanceof TextView ) {

                     ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                     ((TextView) textView).setTextSize((float) 12);
                     ((TextView) textView).setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);

                     ((TextView) textView).setSingleLine(false);

                     // explicitly set layout parameters
                     textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
                     textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                 }
             }
         }

         mTabHst.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272500/android-exception-did-you-forget-to-call-public-void-setup-localactivitymanag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer finally...

```
 Resources res = getResources();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Added_Friends.class);
        Intent j = new Intent(this,Friend_List.class);
        TabHost mTabHst = getTabHost();
        mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator(null,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContent(i));

     mTabHst.addTab(mTabHst.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator(null,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContent(j));


         int tabCount = mTabHst.getTabWidget().getTabCount();
         for (int r = 0; r < tabCount; r++) {
             final View view = mTabHst.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(r);
             if ( view != null ) {
                 // reduce height of the tab
                 view.getLayoutParams().height *= 0.90;

                 //  get title text view
                 final View textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                 if ( textView instanceof TextView ) {

                     ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                     ((TextView) textView).setTextSize((float) 12);
                     ((TextView) textView).setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);

                     ((TextView) textView).setSingleLine(false);

                     // explicitly set layout parameters
                     textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
                     textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                 }
             }
         }

         mTabHst.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Add below xml in your layout...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dip">


    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"  />
      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```