# Android: Fragment with tabs

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

How can I put tabs inside of my fragment? I have been struggling with this and would greatly appreciate some help.

Currently I am getting this error: `Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?`

However, even when I add a call to this I still get a fatal crash with an error:
`Must call setup() that takes a Context and FragmentManager`

This seems to be contradictory....

Below is the relevant Java and XML:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.testtabhost1);

    //LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), false);
    //mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    //mTabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

    //LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), false);
    //mTabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

    Intent q_intent = new Intent (getActivity(), QuestionTabActivity.class);
    Intent a_intent = new Intent (getActivity(), AnswerTabActivity.class);

    View questionIndicator = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Questions");
    View answerIndicator = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Answers");

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("questions").setIndicator(questionIndicator).setContent(q_intent));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("answers").setIndicator(answerIndicator).setContent(a_intent));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return v;
}
```

And the XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.juryroom.qollege_android_v1.ProfileFragment">

    .........
    ...ETC...
    .........

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/testtabhost1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_profile_picture_fragment_circView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:showDividers="none"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

.........
...ETC...
.........

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the design look I'm making: 
[image: My Design]

Comment: Use the new  design library,  I created a full example look this. https://github.com/erikcaffrey/MaterialDesign-NavigationDrawerToggle I hope it helps!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272500/android-exception-did-you-forget-to-call-public-void-setup-localactivitymanag

Comment: @KingofMasses I saw this, and tried the answer, but it didn't work

Comment: @ErikJhordanReyCaffrey That design library looks like its using the actionbar tabs. I want to have tabs in the middle of a fragment.

Comment: if u have the design, post it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil added the design

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I followed that example and is how my code currently is...

Comment: @Pseduosance, i think you dont need tabs for this. You can customize a radio group, with a frame layout under it. depending on selection add the respective fragments to the frame layout.

Comment: Check this http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/05/custom-radio-buttons-example-in-android.html

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil Looks promising, I'll try to implement this after I get some sleep and let you know. Thanks man.

Comment: @Pseduosance, TabLayout is a view that can be accommodated where you need it. but may not be necessary to use tabs you can cutomizar one radio group o simply buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(Constant.BuildingPicture.FRONT_PHOTOS).setIndicator(Constant.BuildingPicture.FRONT_PHOTOS),SiteDataFrontPhotoTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(Constant.BuildingPicture.SATELLITE_PHOTOS).setIndicator(Constant.BuildingPicture.SATELLITE_PHOTOS),SiteDataSatellitePhotoTab.class, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display tabs we don’t have to use any other UI element like TabHost. Action bar has the inbuilt capability of adding tabs. All we have to do is enable it using setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS).

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) is a good description of what you are looking for.

Comment: Where I want the tabs is in a fragment midway in the screen. Can the actionbar do that?