# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have the following activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

        TabHost mainTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.mainTabHost);
        mainTabHost.setup();

        mainTabHost.addTab(mainTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1").setIndicator("", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.d1)).setContent(new Intent(this, Activity1.class)));

        mainTabHost.addTab(mainTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2").setIndicator("", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.d2)).setContent(new Intent(this, Activity2.class)));

        mainTabHost.addTab(mainTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3").setIndicator("", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.d3)).setContent(new Intent(this, Activity3.class)));
    }
}
```

And this is the XML

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/mainTabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activityHorizontalMargin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activityHorizontalMargin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activityVerticalMargin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/mainHomeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

There is another activity, in which tapping a button launches this activity. However, the activity doesn't launch and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nirvanapass/com.nirvanapass.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
```

I have searched online - but whatever solutions I could find use `ActivityGroup` or `TabActivity` - both of which are deprecated. How to tackle this error and solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272500/android-exception-did-you-forget-to-call-public-void-setup-localactivitymanag

Comment: That suggests `ActivityGroup` which is deprecated. Looking for a better way, even if it means I have to re-write my code.

Comment: Well then I would look into the ViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use a modern tab solution. `TabHost` has been obsolete for quite some time. Using an `Intent` for a tab content has been deprecated for **five years**, and it was never a good idea even before then.

Most modern tab implementations use a `ViewPager` with some sort of tabbed indicator. `PagerTabStrip` and `TabLayout` are both in the Android SDK, and the Android Arsenal lists many other tab indicators in [their `ViewPager` category](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111).

If you really want the retro styling of a `TabWidget`, either use `FragmentTabHost`, or use `TabHost` where the tabs are views.

Here are sample apps for:

- [using `PagerTabStrip`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Indicator)
- [using `TabLayout`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DesignSupport/TabLayout)
- [using a third-party tab indicator](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DesignSupport/TabLayoutPizza)
- [using `TabHost` with widgets for tabs](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/Tab)

Comment: Fantastic. I'll try this out and get back (in a few days). Thanks!

Comment: Marking it accepted for now as it seems this is right